# cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' when using Pillow on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, lambda, python-imaging-library

I uploaded Pillow package into AWS Lambda and added it as a layer, but the execution of the lambda function give the `cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (/opt/python/PIL/__init__.py)` error.

What I have done:

1. `pip install pillow -t .` and put `PIL` and `pillow-10.2.0.dist-info` folder into folder `python` and make a zip, and upload the zip into Lambda function as a Layer. Selected runtime as Python 3.12.
2. In my lambda function, I added this layer and set function runtime as 3.12 as well.
3. included the code `from PIL import Image` and it gives me this error.

I've done some search, but all the solutions I've found are very old and is not relevant. Any help is appreciated!